# Component Module WIN 32 Exceptions

Tags: windows-xp

Since I downloaded xp pro, I get an error message that reads as follows:

> SystemComponentModel.Win32Exception:The system cannot find the file
>   specified at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo start Info) at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(StringfileName, String arguments) at
>   MyDownloader.IEPlugin.IEMD.DownloadURL(Stringurl)

What does this mean I have tried to do a restore and nothing seems to work even when I used a registry repair tool.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The IEPlugin thing makes me think you have a plug in for IE that doesn't work.. but, that's a complete guess. I'll look around online a bit and try to find some advice / answers

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe) to investigate (filter for `iexplore.exe`) and use a tool such as [Autoruns](http://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to find a browser helper object (BHO) or Active X component named something with `MyDownloader` in the name. A search through the registry will likely also yield some pointers to the culprit, but above tools should lead you straight to it and faster, plus they come with the means to deactivate/disable the culprit.

Side-note: it is well possible that this is some kind of malicious piece of software. So I'd also recommend a scan with some anti-malware product(s).

The error itself along with the stack backtrace tells you exactly that someone is trying to run a command by means of the .NET wrapper for `ShellExecuteEx` and fails, because the program from that command cannot be found.